# MongoDB "Can't take a write lock while out of disk space"

Tags: mongodb

I'm installing MongoDB to use with Node.JS. I'm following this tutorial to set up mongo

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/

I type

```
mongo
db
use mydb
```

then

```
j = { name : "mongo" }
k = { x : 3 }
db.testData.insert( j )
db.testData.insert( k )
```

it says

```
Can't take a write lock while out of disk space
```

Is there something I need to do with permissions? This is a new Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu. It shouldn't be out of space.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to find this answer to this solution and there's no similar question on Google/Stackexchange

Comment: As this is not a programming question and is system administration, I'd suggest moving your question to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: "It shouldn't be out of space":  I had the same problem and was painfully reminded how little storage space a default AWS node has.  Can you report the result of 'df -h'?

Comment: 99% of your main disk is full.  You're out of space.

Comment: There's like 112M left! :(

Comment: I want to build this to scale by deploying the app to heroku. But for testing the app, I was using Amazon EC ubuntu. How can I set up a dev environment to build a web app when there isn't enough storage?